# Can't boot on battery power. Help!

Tags: boot, grub2, battery

I can't boot without my laptop being plugged in with any flavour(mate/budgie etc) of ubuntu other than vanilla ubuntu(with gnome). I have the same problem when I install different desktop environments. I'm using an Asus TUF laptop with ryzen 5 3550h and nvidia 1650 (mobile). I don't think it's a hardware problem because windows and manjaro boot just fine on battery.

Details: After I choose to boot into ubuntu, I see the logo and everything goes black. On AC Power everything is fine though. (I'm dualbooting ubuntu 20.04 and windows 10).

I've tried the following sollution with no luck:

changing

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT
in

/etc/default/grub
to

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash dis_ucode_ldr"
and running sudo update-grub

Comment: Can you please add some specifics, we don't know what release you are talking about, nor what you mean by *flavours*, as in my experience all *flavors* of Ubuntu are the same as main Ubuntu for the same release (booting is performed by the same base code in all, only GUI software differs but that's after-boot).

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 20.04, and by flavours I mean ubuntu with different desktop environments such as mate, budgie etc. Everything works fine with ubuntu and gnome, but if I choose to install a different desktop environment or install a different iso with a different desktop environment, I have this problem.

Comment: Are you logging in with X or Wayland with GNOME?   As some flavors are limited to X only, thus should be compared to GNOME on X rather than GNOME on Wayland.  (*my own box is a Ubuntu install with xubuntu-desktop & lubuntu-desktop installed so I'm familiar with multiple desktops on the same install*)

Comment: I'm logging in with X

Comment: Have you tried editing the `grub` entry to have it show all messages (ie. ESC and remove the `quiet splash`, single boot only for exploration not permanent change), or boot into runlevel 1 in hopes of gaining more information?  What kernel is the Manjaro using?

Comment: Manjaro was using 5.7 kernel. I don't remember the exact version. Can you tell me what I should do after booting into runlevel 1? I'm fairly new to linux. After i removed "quiet splash" I saw the following :  loading, please wait... starting version 245.4-4ubuntu3.2 Begin: Loading essential drivers ... done Begin: Running /scripts/init-premount ...

Comment: The exact kernel was 5.7.9-1 for manjaro